# Plotting multiple images with subplot

Tags: python

I have 10 images stored in a folder. I wish to plot them side-by-side/together, and I know you can use subplot to plot multiple images at once. Here's my code:

```
def plot_images():
    folder = "digits_pics/ex_0/"
    images = os.listdir(folder)
    print(images)
    i = 0
    for image in images:
        plt.subplot(2,5,i+1)
        im = imread(folder+image)
        i+=1
        imgplot = plt.imshow(im)
    plt.show()
    return
```

When I plot these images, the labels are skewed:

[image: skewed_labels]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you need to keep `i=0` out of your loop?

Comment: awesome, i feel like an idiot. thx :D

Comment: I have a follow-up, see my edit.

Comment: Now it's unclear. Image or more information can clairify problem.

Comment: I uploaded an image, can you not see it? (try right clicking and open in a new tab)

Comment: Try increase index by 2, not 1.

Comment: Add
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.5)
or use plt.tight_layout()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
plt.figure(figsize=[14,10]) # set image size
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.5)# set distance between the subplots
```

before your for loop. You might have to play with the numbers to get the best look.